# Screenshot using Robot.createScreenCapture returning black image?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, awtrobot

I'm trying to capture the screen using the below code on Windows 7

```
 Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
 BufferedImage capture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(screenRect);
 ImageIO.write(capture, "jpg", new File("C:/capture/ScreenShot.jpg"));
```

and this code is returning a black image, don't know why please help.

Imports are as below:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: No issue in code...must be problem in package import... be insure you are import package java.awt.* or anything else???

Comment: @SaurabhGaur i have also added the imports which i'm using and still getting black image as screenshot.

Comment: Why are you not capture screenshot here using Selenium Webdriver????

Comment: follow this link may be it will help...https://community.oracle.com/thread/1289188?start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Is it mandatory to use robot? Cann't we use something else?

Comment: @KishanPatel i can use something else but i'm worried because it's working for most of the people. Let me know if there is another good way of taking screenshots.

Comment: if you want to take screenshot using selenium follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver

Comment: The link Shown by Saurabh Gaur works well. I use that way for taking sceenshots.

Comment: @SaurabhGaur i want to use that robot thing because i don't want to provide the url to web driver i want to capture whatever is open in the browser.

Comment: have you tested a small rectangle?

Comment: for me works correct only on local env, but on remote still return black..

Comment: for me works correct with position and demention
BufferedImage screen = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(pos.x, pos.y, dim.width, dim.height));

Answer (score 1):

Check this, I think it will help you.

```
    public void screenCapture() {
    Dimension dimension = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(dimension);
    BufferedImage screen = robot.createScreenCapture(rectangle);
    try {
        ImageIO.write(screen, "jpg", new File("screenshot.jpg"));
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

And after just use this void. :)

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue on Ubuntu with Java 11 and Java 12, fixed by upgrading to Java 13.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was in wildfly startup mode. When it started as a service, I got a black screen. When I started it manually through standalone.bat the problem went away.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe, there is another ScreenDevice.
Try

```
Robot r = new Robot(GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice());
BufferedImage capture = r.createScreenCapture(screenRect);
```

Comment: No luck. still the same black image as screenshot.